# How do I add clothes/body to the skeleton?

Tags: armature, bones

[image]

I would like to set the skeleton to the body and clothes. I tried to join the clothes to the body and set automatic weights. However the skeleton is only attached to the body.

Comment: hello, when you're talknig about skeleton, do you mean the armature? Maybe share your file so that we can check. When you have body and cloth, a way to parent can be to keep them separated, parent With Automatic Weights, then join the 2 objects, it generally works better this way...

Comment: You'll look at the file? Thank you! Here it is. 
https://files.catbox.moe/l2c56u.blend

Comment: oh ok but it's not a classic armature, so I guess if the clothes were not already parented it will be tedious to do it with this armature